# Water the plants (competitive programming)

Tags: c++, algorithm, greedy

I was trying to solve this proble:

> A gallery with plants is divided into n parts, numbered : 0,1,2,3...n-1. There are provisions for attaching water sprinklers at every partition. A sprinkler with range x at partition i can water all partitions from i-x to i+x.
> Given an array gallery[ ] consisting of n integers, where gallery[i] is the range of sprinkler at partition i (power==-1 indicates no sprinkler attached), return the minimum number of sprinklers that need to be turned on to water the complete gallery.
> If there is no possible way to water the full length using the given sprinklers, print -1.

and this is how I ended up trying-

1. Create a frequency array such that the ith element contains the number of sprinklers that are watering the ith part of the gallery.
2. If any element of this array is zero after going through all the sprinklers, then return -1 as even if all the sprinklers tried they couldn't water each part.
3. Then, `std::stable_sort` all the sprinklers based on their range, in increasing order.
4. Then, remove a sprinkler if it is redundant, starting from the smallest range to the largest.

My implementation of the same-

```
typedef struct sprinkler {
    int l;
    int r;
} sprinkler;

int min_sprinklers(int gallery[], int n)
{
    int freq[n];
    vector<sprinkler> vec; 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) freq[i] = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
        int x = gallery[i];
        if(x == -1) continue;
        int l = max(0, i - x);
        int r = min(n-1, i + x);
        sprinkler s;
        s.l = l;
        s.r = r;
        vec.push_back(s);
        for(int j = l; j <= r; j++) {
            freq[j]++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(freq[i] == 0) return -1;
    }

    stable_sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](sprinkler s1, sprinkler s2) { return s1.r-s1.l < s2.r-s2.l; });

    int sprinklers = vec.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        int l = vec[i].l;
        int r = vec[i].r;
        bool flag = false;
        for(int j = l; j <= r; j++) {
            if(freq[j] == 1) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!flag) {
            for(int j = l; j <= r; j++) freq[j]--;
            sprinklers--;
        }
    }

    return sprinklers;
}
```

But I still seem to be missing something and still don't know what.
Link to try my code:
[https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/410d51d667ab93f2219b15126f001f32e8bb029e/0/?category[]=Greedy&category[]=Greedy&difficulty[]=1&page=1&query=category[]Greedydifficulty[]1page1category[]Greedy#](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/410d51d667ab93f2219b15126f001f32e8bb029e/0/?category%5B%5D=Greedy&category%5B%5D=Greedy&difficulty%5B%5D=1&page=1&query=category%5B%5DGreedydifficulty%5B%5D1page1category%5B%5DGreedy#)

Comment: It seems it's time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt to show us in the question itself. Or how to [edit] your questions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude edited to add code and problem statement

Comment: Here's an example where this algorithm breaks. A gallery of size 200. A small sprinkler in the middle, covering three positions [99, 100, 101]. Two slightly larger sprinklers, covering positions 90-100 and 101-110. Two very large sprinklers, covering 0-98 and 102-200. Your algorithm would turn off the small sprinkler, and would have to use 4 remaining sprinklers; whereas 3 could be sufficient (two big ones, and the small one filling the gap).

Comment: A better algorithm: of all the sprinklers that can cover position 0, pick one that reaches farthest right. Do the same for the first (leftmost) position that it didn't reach - find all sprinklers that can reach it, and pick one that shoots farthest right. Repeat until the rightmost position is covered, or there's one that no sprinkler covers.

Comment: does the above answers  ur `missing something` search ?